# Is it possible to start on the second tab when using the createBottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I want to keep my tab navigator visually to stay in this order: Home tab, Connect tab, Chat tab

But I want to have the Connect tab (the second tab) be the first one that open when the app loads. I don't see a way to add this to the stack navigator without rearranging the order of the tabs. Is there another way to target a tab other then the first one with this structure:

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  LoadingScreen,
  FirstLoginScreen,
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Main: MainScreen,
    EmailLogin: EmailLoginScreen,
    PhoneLogin: RegisterScreens,
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Home: createStackNavigator({
        HomeScreen,
        EditAccountScreen,
        EditPreferencesScreen,
        EditProfileScreen,
        ProfileCardScreen,
      }),
      Connect: ConnectionsScreen,
      Chat: createStackNavigator({
        AllChatScreen,
        SingleChat,
      })
    },
    {
      defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => {
          const {routeName} = navigation.state;
          if (routeName === "Home") {
            return <MaterialIcons name={"home"} size={20} color={tintColor} />;
          } else if (routeName === "Connect") {
            return <MaterialIcons name={"link"} size={20} color={tintColor} />;
          } else if (routeName === "Chat") {
            return <MaterialIcons name={"chat"} size={20} color={tintColor} />;
          }
        },
      }),
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: Colors.Brick,
        inactiveTintColor: Colors.Gray,
      },
    }
  ),
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a prop named ***"initialRouteName"*** with the name of the route you want to be displayed when you entered the navigation first

[here you can fine more details with React Navigation V5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#initialroutename)